# Browser returns same zip file even if server returns a different zip file

Tags: python, flask

Im using flask to serve a zip file to my frontend, with ReactJs, HTML and CSS. During the server runtime, the contents of the zip files may be changed. However, I've noticed that when I downloaded an empty zip file a few times, and when the server contents are updated, accessing the link still returns me an empty zip file.
Furthermore, even when the server is taken offline, accessing the same link will still give me the same empty zip file downloadable.
I suspect that the browser is caching the response of the server previously, and thus the same empty zip file will be returned repeatedly.
What should I do to either the server or the frontend to prevent the issue of returning the same file from happening?

```
@app.route('/download-zip/<classID>')
def request_zip(classID):
    data = BytesIO() 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(data, mode='w') as z:
        try:
            img_folder=r"./data/attendance_images"
            class_img_folder=os.path.join(img_folder,classID)
            img_list=os.listdir(class_img_folder)
            for img_name in img_list:
                img_path=os.path.join(class_img_folder,img_name)
                z.write(img_path, arcname=img_name)

            log_folder=r"./data/attendance_logs"
            log_file=os.path.join(log_folder,classID+".txt")
            z.write(log_file,arcname=classID+".txt")
        except:
            pass

    data.seek(0)
    
    return send_file(
        data,
        mimetype='application/zip',
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename='data.zip'
    )
```

The HTML is simply

```
<button id="generatelog" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/download-zip/30021';">Generate Log</button>
```

Comment: can you provide the javascript/react code which is handling the transfer here.and make sure your api response is not being cached by react during runtime, else it will return the cached response instead of the actual response

Comment: I've updated the post to include the frontend. It is simply a button with a link to the zip file downloadable. How do I not make this specific part of the code not cacheable is my question, assuming that my theory of the browser caching data is correct

Comment: check the network call happening in the network tab and see if it giving a cached response without acutally hitting the api at run time.   try disabling the caching in the html and see if it works. <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">  . Or one more way for getting the data is onclick of button, call a javascript function which does an api call your url with no-store cache header.